# Visting a laravel project with localhost via apache

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I have just installed a laravel project into my `Home/public_html` folder. I gave it a name, let's call it `laravel` for this purpose. So the template installed to `Home/public_html/laravel` and then I ran a `composer install`. I got a database password error. I fixed that, ran it again, and all went well. I then created a migration, a controller, and a view. I tried to navigate to it via *localhost/laravel/public/events* (events is my created view) I get a 404. I remembered I needed a config file in `etc/apache2/sites-available` I created the config file with this structure:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/laravel/public/

<Directory /home/user/public_html/laravel/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I then created a `symlink` into the `sites-enabled` folder. That didn't help.
I then navigated to `localhost/laravel` and it just gives me the directory structure.

What have I missed? What have I done wrong?

I have another folder inside `public_html` with its own config file that works perfectly (it points to `home/user/public_html/`. It also has a symlink. Is there something in each project that tell the project which config to use? Do they just work? My knowledge of this really stops here. Basically, I've exhausted what I know. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Oh and I have restarted apache as well. - a couple of times through the steps I just detailed.

Comment: define [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) and [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

Comment: post your routes file too.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the Laravel instalation to the web server is never a good idea. Since you can access the file listing of the `laravel` folder, I believe your document root is set to `/home/user/public_html`.

Better approach to solve this problem will be as follows.

1. Keep entire laravel installation outside `public_html` directory. Let's assume inside `/home/user/development`
2. You may need to add following to the apache configuration below `DocumentRoot`.

   ```
   Alias /laravel /home/user/development/laravel/public
   ```
3. Add following `Directory` Configuration

   ```
   <Directory /home/user/development/laravel/public/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
4. Add following to `.htaccess` file in `/home/user/development/laravel/public/` below `RewriteEngine` rule.

   ```
    RewriteBase /laravel
   ```

Restart the apache2 server, your site should be available on localhost/laravel. Make sure there are no folder named `laravel` inside the `public_html` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought it would work. Looks like it didn't, though. Is there anything else to check?

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: DocumentRoot /home/user/development/laravel/public/

Comment: Do you have any other vhost conf where DocumentRoot is `/home/user/public_html`? Try adding `Alias` and `Directory` there. Make sure vhost conf with `DocumentRoot /home/user/development/laravel/public/ ` disabled.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I have two other conf files where the `DocumentRoot` is `/home/user/public_html`. They have no `Alias`. What would that have to do with a conf with a `DocumentRoot` at `/home/user/development/laravel/public`? How do I disable a conf file? By removing it from the sites-enabled folder?

Comment: I even added an alias /laravel to a diff conf file and was able to get to my project through `localhost/laravel/proj_name` which was inside my `public_html`. Is it not working because I have two conf files?

Comment: Disable conf file - remove the symlink from `sites-enabled` directory or use `sudo a2dissite <conf>`. You should add `Alias` to the conf file which contains `/home/user/public_html` as Document Root.