# Install laravel in a subfolder via ftp

Tags: php, laravel-4, ftp

I'm working with a server that I can only use FTP, so I have my laravel project in a folder inside www named 'laravel', I want to see my project by clicking domain.com/laravel, inside this www folder I have others folders with others projects I don't think that I can use the root to upload my laravel project like I saw in many tutorials.
Now If  I visit domain.com/laravel i only see a list of directories ,Is possible to view my project working at /laravel ??

Thanks!

Comment: Try domain.com/laravel/public

Comment: But I want to access direct by domain.com/laravel

Comment: Maybe u can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622219/visting-a-laravel-project-with-localhost-via-apache

Comment: This solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683046/how-to-install-laravel-4-to-a-web-host-subfolder-without-publicly-exposing-app

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to add a custom mod rewrite config or configure your apache virtual host directory to be laravel/public